Should eTags be unique for same URL but with different request parameters?
Say we are creating a server resource with a set of data with rows 1,2,3 and a REST endpoint that returns one row specified by parameter "row" on GET requests. We have a last modified date that changes for the entire data set and want to use that as the eTag for responses.
My expectation is that clients that request "row=1" and receive the eTag in the response are not going to then use that tag to make a request for "row=2", but only for later queries with "row=1". Therefore it should not matter that the eTag returned is the same (since it is using the modified date of the entire set) for a request with "row" 1, 2, or 3. Is that correct?

You're correct etags don't need to be unique across different resources. They just need to be unique for a specific representation of a specific resource.
If the URL is different, it's a different resource. With the one exception that a change in the #fragment will still fetch the same resource. I assume you mean values after the ? (query parameters) when you talk about 'request parameters', and indeed these two are different URLs / resources:
http://example/some-resource?val=1
http://example/some-resource?val=2

The full 'key' of the cache that the browser maintains actually can also include more information from the HTTP request and response. See the Vary header for more information.

Yes, that is what I meant by request parameters. Thank you for answering.
